# Getting `spss.Submit` to log commands into the `output` window?

Tags: spss

When I execute spss syntax commands from a `.sps` script, each command is written to the output window before it executes giving me a clear log of exactly how an output was created.

Even if the command is an `INSERT` command executing a different script - I get a log of the commands from that script.

This is very useful for many reasons:

- sanity checking - I can always see exactly what went in to creating a specific output (which filters I used, etc.)
- recreation - I (or someone else with this output) can easily re-run the same commands because they're right there.
- debugging - if there's an error, I can see which commands caused it

However, when I run commands using `spss.Submit` inside a python block (in a `BEGIN PROGRAM-END PROGRAM` block), the actual commands called aren't logged into the output window.

I know I can find a full log in a log file - but that's not helpful.

Is there a way to tell spss to continue to log all the commands in the output window?

Comment: Had the same question, could not find an answer. What I do is either print the submitted syntax (into the log, using python `print`, or output it to a textfile)

Comment: @horace_vr I've considered it, but it doesn't work with `INSERT` (won't log the commands in that `.spa` file)

Comment: I do that before spss.Submit(mysyntax) - in the python code, I write the submitted "mysyntax" to a text file, and save it somehwere locally

Comment: @horace_vr yes, that's what I tried - but if I do `spss.Submit("INSERT FILE='<filename>.sps'.")`, I don't get a log of the commands inside `<filename>.sps`. That's my main issue :(

Comment: what do you have in filename.sps ? Python or spss language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set mprint on.` before the `begin program` statement to have the syntax that is run via `spss.Submit()`show up in the output window. I like simpy putting it on the very top of my syntax file as a "set it and forget it".

For example like so:

```
set mprint on. 

begin program python3. 
import spss

vars = list(range(1,11))

for var in vars: 
    spss.Submit(f'compute v{var} = 0. ')

end program.
```